# AppleScript texting app messages the wrong person

Tags: applescript, imessage

I have this script that sends multiple text messages, but sometimes the script will send the first message to another number that I've recently messaged in Messages. I can't seem to find a pattern either, sometimes the bug happens and sometimes it sends all of the texts to the right number.

```
--usage: osascript sendMessage phone_number text_to_send amount_to_send
--Sends targetMessage to targetBuddyPhone repeatAmount times to targetMessage   

on run {targetBuddyPhone, targetMessage, repeatAmount}
    set counter to 0
    repeat while counter < repeatAmount
        tell application "Messages"
            send targetMessage to buddy targetBuddyPhone of service "SMS"
            set counter to counter + 1
        end tell
    end repeat
end run
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: This is not the cause of your issue however I'd place `set counter to counter + 1` outside of and after the `tell application "Messages"` block but inside the `repeat while counter < repeatAmount` block. I say this because the `counter` is really more so a part of the `repeat` _loop_ then what specifically Messages is doing. While it works either way nonetheless IMO it's a more proper way to code it. But to each their own. As to what's causing your issue, sorry but I'm not in a position to test. It will be interesting to see it this can be debugged!

Comment: What is the type and value of `targetBuddyPhone`?